# JavaFX TextArea Vertical Alignment

Tags: css, javafx, textarea

I'm trying to center the text in a text box in the middle of the text box, vertically. I've been able to center the text horizontally in java by using `textArea.setStyle("-fx-text-alignment: center");`.

I thought about the possibility of using parameters like Center Center or Bottom Center to achieve these results through the -fx-text-alignment string, but I'm handling the horizontal and vertical alignment through two different buttons on my window, and would therefore not want to implement logic to relate the two methods.

I have tried to toggle the `-fx-alignment` of the textArea as well, without any success.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could get my text to appear in the vertical center of the textArea?

EDIT: Below is my current window, the text area I am attempting to manipulate is in the center.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by vertically centering a text in a `textbox` ? a `textbox` is single-line, be more specific !

Comment: @James_D Why use a tall `TextField` when there is a control made for this purpose `TextArea`, it doesn't make sense !

Comment: Just to add some clarification, I am using a TextArea rather than a TextField for my application, as it is a 'text editor' and is used for multiple lines of input, rather than a single line of text input. I have added an image to the original post as well for visualization.

Comment: I had already understood for the error and I apologize, my next question was about the taller TextField,  but as you say it is not the question here !

Comment: The only way I can find to make this work involves some really ugly hacks of the text area layout. There doesn't seem to be any other way to get a handle on this.

Answer (score 4):

I can only find a solution to this by some brutally ugly hacking of the layout of the text area using some CSS lookups and listeners on the sizes of various child nodes of the text area.

Perhaps someone can come up with something more robust, but I don't see any way into this with the API.

Here's an example that works:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextAreaAlignment extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

        Scene scene = new Scene(textArea, 400, 400);

        hackTextAreaLayout(textArea);


        scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


    }

    private void hackTextAreaLayout(TextArea textArea) {
        textArea.applyCss();
        textArea.layout();

        ScrollPane textAreaScroller = (ScrollPane) textArea.lookup(".scroll-pane");
        Text text = (Text) textArea.lookup(".text");


        ChangeListener<? super Bounds> listener = 
                (obs, oldBounds, newBounds) -> centerTextIfNecessary(textAreaScroller, text);
        textAreaScroller.viewportBoundsProperty().addListener(listener);
        text.boundsInLocalProperty().addListener(listener);

    }

    private void centerTextIfNecessary(ScrollPane textAreaScroller, Text text) {
        double textHeight = text.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();
        double viewportHeight = textAreaScroller.getViewportBounds().getHeight();
        double offset = Math.max(0, (viewportHeight - textHeight) / 2 );
        text.setTranslateY(offset);
        Parent content = (Parent)textAreaScroller.getContent();
        for (Node n : content.getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
            if (n instanceof Path) { // caret
                n.setTranslateY(offset);
            }
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

style.css just has

```css
.text-area .text {
    -fx-text-alignment: center ;
}
```

For reasons I can't quite grasp, this doesn't work at all if there is no style sheet attached.

Comment: This seems a bit complex for what I'm trying to accomplish here, as I am looking to change the vertical position of the text within the text area between three states - 'Top' 'Middle' and 'Bottom. Correct me if I'm wrong -- but it appears your method checks if centering is neccesary and translates the text accordingly.

I was able to use the `setStyle` method to translate the text in the y-direction, however the caret remains at the top of the text area, even though the text appeared lower than it's original position.

Comment: @dibiasem It centers if there's any available space. If the user typed more text than would fit in the visual bounds of the text area (so a vertical scroll bar appeared) then you wouldn't be able to (or want to) align at all anyway. So to align to the top, `offset` would be zero, and to align to the bottom, `offset` would be `viewportHeight - textHeight` (without dividing by 2).

Comment: @dibiasem Unfortunately the caret doesn't appear to have a style class, so I don't see any way to translate it using CSS. How are you controlling how far to translate it with `setStyle(...)`? If the user typed multiple lines (or if the text area changed size) you need to adjust...

Comment: To set the style to move the text I first set a node `final Node font1 = textArea.lookup(".text");` which examines the `textArea`'s style class (`text-area`) and manipulates the `.text` node. Once that has been established, I implemented the following; `font1.setStyle("-fx-translate-y: 0");`

Comment: In terms of the user entering in multiple lines, this is something I considered initially, but decided it went beyond the scope of the editor. The window I'm creating is designed for simplicity, so handling dynamic alignment of the text may be beyond the purpose itself. However, the solution you provided is definitely appreciated and I will be sure to reference the method you used in more complex settings.

Comment: @dibiasem Uhhh.. wait. You don't want the user to enter multiple lines? So why not just use a text field? If you want a single line text control that just appears bigger, you should be able to do that fairly simply with padding or something. (In fact, [`TextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#textfield) supports `fx-alignment` directly in its CSS properties.)

Comment: Upon re-reading my previous comment, I don't believe I was very clear when referring to 'multiple lines'. Users will typically enter in multiple lines of text, but it is atypical for a user to want their multiple lines exactly centered in the middle of the text area -- this is a simple editor and translating the text _close_ to the center or what appears to be centered will suffice.

Comment: The fact of the matter is that there does not appear to be a simple way to change the vertical alignment of text in a method similar to the -fx-text-alignment option that is available for horizontal alignment of a text area.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense (I guess), and I agree with your last assessment. But for the code you posted in your comment, surely once you have gone to the trouble of getting a reference to the text node, it makes more sense just to call `setTranslateY(...)` instead of calling `setStyle(...)` to set the `translateY` property. (For one thing, at least it is typesafe...). And also, if there are multiple lines and you translate it, then don't you risk some of it becoming impossible to see unless you actually do a computation?

Comment: Using `setTranslateY(...)` definitely optimizes what I'm trying to do, as once a style is set for a specific node, entering a new `setStyle` statement overwrites the previous one. 
Yes, you are correct, setting a static amount of translation may result in the text being completely obstructed to the user, especially in the case of the text alignment being set to 'Bottom' within my program, as having two lines of text will surely exceed the bounds of the textArea.